# Circuit of a potentiometer with switch

Tags: power-supply, resistors, switches, power-electronics, potentiometer

in [a device I have bought](https://elsalvador.desertcart.com/products/62048617-kkmoon-excellent-10-50v-60a-3000w-dc-motor-speed-control-pwm-hho-rc-controller-12v-24v-36v-40v-50v-speed-adjuster-with-case) there is this potentiometer with switch:
[image]

It has 5 pins instead of 3 as a normal potentiometer: two of them are connected to VCC and GND, the other ones i do not know (there is not a schematic of that device).

Do you know the equivalent circuit of this potentiometer with switch? I need for it because I want to measure the voltage across one portion of the potentiometer while tuning it.

Answer (score 3):

The switch and the potentiometer are completely independant.
the 2-pin connector is for the switch and the 3-pin for the potentiometer.
VCC and ground are connected to the lateral pins of the pentiometer the middle one is the output variable voltage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I have this doubt: if the switch is closed, will GND and VCC be shorted and the potentiometer will be bypassed? How is this possible?

Comment: the swicth is not connected to the potentiometer unless you connect it. It is on the 2-pin connector. the potentiometer is on the 3-pin connector

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffJWg6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. This is what you've got.*

> It has 5 pins instead of 3 as a normal potentiometer:

Look into it. It should be very clear that there are two independent layers or wafers.

> ... two of them are connected to VCC and GND,

Make sure you don't connect the switch wires to V<sub>CC</sub> and GND. If you do you will short-circuit the supply and possibly damage the switch.

> ... the other ones i do not know (there is not a schematic of that device).

You should be able to figure it out with the above diagram and a resistance meter.

> Do you know the equivalent circuit of this potentiometer with switch?

You've got it.

> I need for it because I want to measure the voltage across one portion of the potentiometer while tuning it.

Measure between any two terminals while rotating the shaft.